# how to calculate value counts when we have more than one value in a colum in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

df,

```
Name
Sri
Sri,Ram
Sri,Ram,kumar
Ram
```

I am trying to calculate the value counts for each value.
I am not getting my output when using

```
 df["Name"].values_count()
```

my desired output is,

```
 Sri     3
 Ram     3
 Kumar   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` the column, `stack` to long format, then `count`:

```
df.Name.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()

#Sri      3
#Ram      3
#kumar    1
#dtype: int64
```

Or maybe:

```
df.Name.str.get_dummies(',').sum()

#Ram      3
#Sri      3
#kumar    1
#dtype: int64
```

Or concatenate before *value_counts*:

```
pd.value_counts(pd.np.concatenate(df.Name.str.split(',')))

#Sri      3
#Ram      3
#kumar    1
#dtype: int64
```

---

*Timing*:

```
%timeit df.Name.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop

%timeit df.Name.str.get_dummies(',').sum()
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop

%timeit pd.value_counts(pd.np.concatenate(df.Name.str.split(',')))
#1000 loops, best of 3: 573 µs per loop

# option from @Bharathshetty 
from collections import Counter
%timeit pd.Series(Counter((df['Name'].str.strip() + ',').sum().rstrip(',').split(',')))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 498 µs per loop

# option inspired by @Bharathshetty 
%timeit pd.value_counts(df.Name.str.cat(sep=',').split(','))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 483 µs per loop
```

Comment: what if I have lower case "sri" in index 2nd row, I want to include tht too

Comment: If you want to ignore case, you can convert it to lower/upper case before proceeding. `df.Name.str.lower()....`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean *apply ignorecase*. I don't think you can do `ignore case` while value counting. What's wrong with `str.lower()`?

Comment: that will also work fine, is it possible without converting it to lower?
like using re.IGNORECASE

Comment: @pyd no lower is lower and upper is upper you cant ignore case like that while comparing.

Comment: @Psidom can you also add timings for `pd.Series(Counter((df['Name'].str.strip() + ',').sum().rstrip(',').split(',')))`. Felt it is faster than all of the options.

Comment: That's regular expression option. I am pretty sure you can't do things like that in `value_counts`.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Sure, will do. Looks like an interesting option.

Comment: And for a large dataframe `counter` gives 1.78 ms and `np.concatenate `gives 12ms. I dont suggest numpy for string operations.

Comment: Deserves an upvote for the inspired option :). I was thinking only join and forgot cat. Really nice one.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I agree. `numpy` seems indeed not optimized for string operations.

Comment: @Bharathshetty, in Jezrael answer we are applying re.IGNORECASE that's why i asked, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930681/mapping-matching-word-count-on-a-column-using-pandas-in-python

Comment: @Bharathshetty Join and split is the trick here. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: re.IGNORECASE applies when you are using regex related methods, such as str.contains, str.findall, str.extract, etc. `value_counts` is not one of them.

Comment: @pyd Regex is used to match the pattern not compare. Here we compare two strings to increase the count. Don't fall into misconception that we can compare two different cases as one since both have different ascii values.  .tolower or toupper is the fastest approach.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation @Bharath shetty, Psidom .

From where I can learn more about pandas any online resources?

Comment: Keep tuned to stack overflow try to answer questions, best way to learn pandas.