# how to match a word in a datacolumn with a list of values and applying ignorecase in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
Name
Ram is one of the key ram
Kumar is playing cricket
Ravi is playing and ravi is a good player
```

and a list

```
my_list=["Ram","ravi"]
```

and my desired dataframe is,

```
desired_df,
Name                                        Match    Count 
Ram is one of the key ram                   Ram      1
Kumar is playing cricket                 
Ravi is playing and ravi is a good player   ravi     1
```

I tried

```
 extracted = df.str.findall('(' + '|'.join(my_list) + ')', 
 flags=re.IGNORECASE).apply(set)
 but I am getting like,
 Match
 Ram,ram
 Ravi,ravi
```

but I cannot achieve my desired output, please help.

Comment: Why is count 1. Aint that suppose to be 2 ?

Comment: @Bharath, i think OP wants to use case-sensitive search

Comment: Why ignore case in first place then ? Bit unclear here

Comment: @Bharath, oops, i missed that part...

Comment: Yes, I want to apply ignore case

Comment: @pyd. please provide a __reproducible__ data set and your desired data set

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
new_l = [i.lower() for i in my_list]
extracted = df['Name'].str.lower().str.findall('(' + '|'.join(new_l) + ')').apply(set)


df['Match'] = extracted.apply(','.join)
df['count'] = extracted.apply(len)
```

```
                                          Name     Match  count
0                      Ram is one of the key ram       ram      1
1                       Kumar is playing cricket                0
2  Ravi Ram is playing and ravi is a good player  ram,ravi      2
```

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305897/matching-rows-between-dataframes-in-pandas-in-python/47307029#47307029

Comment: I was working on that solution but my friends called so had to go. Its not an easy task will give a try. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [187]: pat = '({})'.format('|'.join(my_list))

In [188]: df['Match'] = df['Name'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)

In [190]: df['Count'] = df.Name.str.count(pat)

In [191]: df
Out[191]:
                                                Name Match  Count
0                          Ram is one of the key ram   Ram      1
1                           Kumar is playing cricket   NaN      0
2  Ravi is playing and ravi (ravi ravi) is a good...  ravi      3  # i've intentionally added `(ravi ravi)`
```

Comment: I dont want to check in "Name" `df['Count'] = df.Name.str.count(pat)`

In some cases, If i have Ram,ravi under Match column then count value should be 2 so I want to separate the words by (,) and take count

Comment: Why there is `In [187]:` type of thing in most of the pandas related answers ?

Comment: @RaheelKhan, `iPython` (interactive console Python) marks input commands and output this way